# Retrieving information of validated user in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework, authentication

I was following this tutorial at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/380900/WCF-Authentication-and-Authorization-in-Enterprise

Now I have it logging in and everything, no problems infact it works just like it should. I've even added some cryptography to it using MD5 hashing. But I'm not sure how to get the users information. So when they call the Utility service, how would I query the database for that specific user?

```
    [PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = "Read")]
    public Data.UserProfiles ViewProfile()
    {
        using (var context = new DatabaseEntities())
        {
           var user = context.UserProfiles.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserName == ???)
           return user;
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you are using the WCF in web application you can store the user details in cookie as the CodeProject article does or you can follow WCF Authentication as here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff405740.aspx

Comment: further on in that article, it has you encrypt that information, which makes alot of sence, What would be the best way to securely get the user details?

Comment: var currentUser = new WindowsPrincipal((WindowsIdentity)
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity);

Comment: figured it out already, Forgot to update the post. here is the solution I used: var callerUserName = Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name; Which is very similar to yours except it appears you're creating a new object as where I am using a static property, Any information you have on the differences, if any?

Comment: @MilanRaval Also, all your answers have been correct. If you wouldn't mind composing an answer I will select it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the WCF in web application you can store the user details in cookie as the CodeProject article does or you can follow WCF Authentication as here: msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff405740.aspx

Use below code to get user:
var currentUser = new WindowsPrincipal((WindowsIdentity) System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity);